# curl multiple requests cookie issue

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl multi API for multiple curl requests.

first I'm using a single request to login to a site and save the cookie file.
then I'm using the curl multi API to get some data from that site.

The problem I'm facing is that from some reason the cookie file does not get read and I'm redirecting to the main login page.

I must say that this work once in awhile so I can't point what went wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 
[php pear HTTP_REQUEST](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/)

and store the cookie data, the functions setCookies and getCookies are your friends.